# Nueva instancia de EC2 no aparece en el panel de AWS

Tags: aws, ec2

Ayer he configurado y lanzado una instancia de t3a.small con ubuntu server en AWS, trabaje un par de horas con ella y al terminar la detuve.

Hoy cuando me dirijo al dashboard de EC2 para lanzar la instancia nuevamente, me encuentro con que no aparece en la lista, únicamente veo otra que ya tenia configurada previamente.

Mi nueva instancia tenia asignada una IP elástica, al enviar un ping no me responde como es natural al estar la instancia detenida.

Esta situación ya se había presentada con la instancia que actualmente me aparece, la di de alta, me apareció en el dashboard y luego desapareció por unas 24 horas para luego volver a aparecer sola.

Previamente he lanzado algunas otras instancias de EC2 sin que esta situación se hubiera presentado o al menos no que me hubiera dado cuenta.

Como puedo lanzar nuevamente la instancia para poder utilizarla si no se muestra en mi panel?

[image: Imagen del dashboard al momento del post]

Answer (score 1):

Pueden pasar dos cosas:

- Alguien ha terminado la instancia
- Estás en una región diferente (solo se ven las instancias que están en la región seleccionada)

Si estás seguro de que la región es la correcta, entonces es probable que alguien la haya eliminado.

Para saber qué ha pasado tienes que ir al servicio CloudTrail. Aquí se registran todos los eventos que se realizan a través de las diferentes APIs de AWS.

No creo que tengas el instanceId de la instancia apuntado así que no podrás localizar la instancia usando este parámetro... pero puedes buscar por eventos determinados, así que haz una búsqueda por eventos. En el tipo de filtro eliges `Event Name`. El evento en sí se llama `TerminateInstances`. Si tienes suerte podrás localizar al responsable de haber terminado tu instancia, así como la fecha y hora del suceso.

Otra forma de localizar tu instancia (para ver qué ha pasado con ella) es, sabiendo la hora aproximada a la que la detuviste, realizas una búsqueda del evento `StopInstances`. Una vez localizada tu instancia, haces una búsqueda usando el filtro `Resource name` y pegas el identificador de tu instancia.